# Who played the Airperson who was verbally shoved aside by McKay in "The Intruder"?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis, production, actor-identification

Who portrays the delightful Airperson to whom McKay barks "*Airperson, don't be there!*" around midway through *Stargate: Atlantis*'s excellent second-season episode [S02E02], "The Intruder"?

[image: Screenshot of the scene in question]

As she is a wordless extra, this information may not exist publicly. But you never know.

Comment: I'm unsure why this has been flagged for closure. I'm quite interested to find out who she is and this seems perfectly well suited for the "actor identification" tag wiki

Comment: I saw during the credits where they show "Airman". Flashed by too quick and could see it, then couldn't get back there to figure it out (on the DVD), but even so, I doubt this is the same person who is being sought after. ... Nope, the "Airman" is a guy, so leaves it out for sure.

Comment: Doesn't help in this case but your goto resource for stuff like this IMDB. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0709250/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast

Comment: @Wudang: Yes but, as you've said, it doesn't help in this case, hence the question :)

Answer (score -3):

I think it might have been Riley DeLuise—she would only have been 12 at the time, but other pics I’ve found of her seem to show her as tall for her age, and it seemed very obvious that Peter DeLuise, who directed the episode, took great care to make sure that the girl’s face was seen onscreen. Riley is On her father’s right in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Your answer seems to hinge largely based on the looks of the actress at the time, could you [edit] in one of these images you’ve found as evidence it is her?

Comment: It doesn't especially look like her. Also the extra has a facial mole that Riley DeLuise doesn't have. Obviously that could be makeup, but I don't see why they would have added it.

Comment: No adolescent wants to be seen with a pimple. Could be easier to use makeup to turn a pimple into a mole than to try making it invisible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the effort, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Valorum and Gaultheria: Watch the episode again; what you’re seeing as a facial mole is actually the end of her headset mike.  I agree that in the photo of her with her father and sister she seems to have a somewhat rounder face, but that could be due to her having aged a couple of years in the interim.

Comment: Upon re-consideration, the girl in the episode has more of a retroussé nose than does Riley DeLuise, so I retract my theory. Damn! I sure thought I had solved the mystery for a moment, there....

Comment: [David DeLuise](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_DeLuise), not Peter as claimed in your answer, is Riley's father.

Answer (score -3):

This is probably [Heather Doerksen](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1976541/), also known for *Once upon a time*. She is listed in the [IMDB cast list for the episode](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0709250/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) as "Bridge Pilot", just before a male cast member listed as "airman".

The actress's recent IMDB picture makes it hard to recognize her in Stargate: Atlantis, but [a Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=heather+doerksen&prmd=inv&source=lnms&tbm=isch), as well as [the actress's own bio page](https://www.heatherdoerksen.com/bio/), reveal some pictures of her closer to 2005 when the episode aired.

Comment: To me, Doerksen looks like the crew member at _left_ in the OP still image, not the _right_.

Comment: https://gatecast.co.uk/stargate-birthdays-february-12th-4.html - It's not her. Heather Doerksen plays Captain Pat Meyers; http://dsds2009.info/maqhiar-heather-doerksen-stargate.htm