# Which is the first scene in "Matrix" where the brand "Nokia" appears?

Tags: the-matrix

Which is the first scene in "Matrix" where the brand "Nokia" appears? It also appears in the scene in Metacortex Bulding, where Neo/Thomas Anderson works.

Comment: Are you asking about being able to see the brand name, or an item that is Nokia related (e.g you can see a Nokia phone, but not the logo)?

Comment: Nope, you can actually see the name. Like Panasonic in the clock and the headphones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first scene in which the Nokia logo appears is just after the "*Heart 'o' The City*" fight involving Trinity and the police officers, [three minutes into the film](https://youtu.be/u31OjOPF-ZI?t=2m1s).

[image]

Comment: You're always reading these impossible-to-read snippets of text from screenshots, like [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126184/what-were-the-titles-of-the-seventeen-dvds-owned-by-sally-sparrow). Are you a cyborg?

Comment: @amaranth - I just squint and get *really* close to the screen.

Comment: Not a Cyborg, I´d watched the movie too many times. It´s like "flight club", a weird movie, I think you have to watched many times to detect a man that appears and disappears in some scenes. The movie is not science fiction, perhaps the connection with "The Matrix" is that Helena Bonham Carter plays an important role, remember that she also acts in Terminator Salvation.